# Settings after AJAX call

Tags: 7, commerce, ajax

I have a page that contains lots of products (node with commerce form) that is formed in custom theme function (template).
I update them by ajax, but forms of updated products do not work. I googled, that it is because `Drupal.settings` javascript form needs to be updated. I tried to do this in such way on my ajax callback function.

```
  $javascript = drupal_add_js(NULL, NULL);
  $commands[] = ajax_command_settings(array($javascript['settings']['data'][0]), $merge=TRUE);
  return array(
    '#type' => 'ajax',
    '#commands' => $commands,
  );
```

It does not work. Nothing changed really.

My full ajax callback:

```
function products_ajax_callback() {
  $commands = array();
  $commands[] = ajax_command_html('#block-system-main', _all_my_products());


  return array(
    '#type' => 'ajax',
    '#commands' => $commands,
  );
}

function _all_my_products(){
      // loading nodes
      $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($result['node']));
      return theme('products_list_in_shop', array('nodes' => $nodes));
}
```

And my theme function of all products:

```
function theme_products_list_in_shop($variables) {
  $output = '<div class="view view-products-for-homepage">';    
      foreach ($variables['nodes'] as $node) {
        $output .= theme('product_in_shop', array('node' => $node));
      }
  $output .= '</div>';
  return $output;
}
```

And theme `product_in_shop` - template, where I render form in such way:

```
<div class="shop-cart">
  <?php
    $order_id = 0;
    $line_item = commerce_line_item_new($product->type, $order_id);
    $line_item->data['context']['product_ids'] = array($product->product_id);
    $line_item->quantity = 1;
    // need to create config for quantity
    $qty = 1;
    $form_id = commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_id(array($product->product_id), $qty);
    $addtocart_form = drupal_get_form($form_id, $line_item);
    $addtocart_form['submit']['#theme'][] = 'vtcommerce_button_small';
    $addtocart_form['#action'] = '/shop';
    print render($addtocart_form);
  ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This might help: https://www.drupal.org/node/1950220

Comment: I seen it. But it does not help

Comment: Also, you can just pass `TRUE` as the second argument, not `$merge=TRUE`.

Comment: If the above comment does not fix your issue, please post your entire Ajax callback, as well as the code for the form element that the ajax callback is attached to.

Comment: @Jaypan I have edited my question and added some more code of my module